# Specificity in importing python module?

Tags: python, import, module, serial-port, pyserial

I've been working with the PySerial library for python[Pyserial API](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html), and I can't seem to understand why I have to specifically import a certain part of the module.

This will give me an error:

```
import serial
for item in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    print item
```

The above snippet will return "AttributeError: type object 'Serial' has no attribute 'tools'"

If I import that attribute specifically, I get no errors:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
for item in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    print item
```

Can someone help me understand why the first import won't run the comports() method?

I understand that importing fewer items into memory is a best practice, but I'm also using other methods from the PySerial module. It seems redundant to import both serial and serial.tools.list_ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `serial` will result in the creation of all names that the module creates. This sounds self-obvious until you realize that `serial` does not create any attribute called "tools" within it. This is in fact a separate module.

`import` does you the favor of importing parent modules, which is why importing `serial.tools.list_ports` also imports `serial.tools`. It does *also* import `serial`, but you should import it explicitly rather than having Python do it for you by accident.

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

 ...
Explicit is better than implicit.
 ...
```